# Unable to access private member - template and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, unique-ptr

I have the following code:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T, size_t Level>
class Foo
{
    friend class Foo<T, Level + 1>;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T> ElmPtr;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Foo<ElmPtr, Level - 1>> NodePtr;        

    public:
    Foo() {
        // no errors
        auto c = children;
    }

    Foo(int n) {
        // !!! compiler error !!!
        auto c = children;
    }

    std::array<NodePtr, 4> children;            
};

template<typename T>
class Foo<T, 0>
{
    friend class Foo<T, 1>;

    public:
    Foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int, 1> foo1;
}
```

I get the following error:

> error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access
>   private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

Why? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Both constructors give an error for me, and it's because you're trying to copy a `std::unique_ptr`, which is impossible. You have to either move from it or bind it to a reference.

Comment: You'll need to use `auto c = std::move(children);` in both places. And we can't tell you why it compiles in once place and not the other because you haven't provided an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Praetorian: How is this not a SSCCE? It's short, it's compilable.  Sadly it's missing the correct `#include <...>` lines, but this is __far__ more than we normally get.

Comment: g++ 4.8..2 shows an error in the default constructor, too

Comment: @Nick: The problem is that the code you provided doesn't give the errors you describe in any compiler I can find.  Not clang, not GCC, and not MSVC even.  The second C in SSCCE stands for "Correct" and one thing that means is "the example... causes the exact error message about which needs solving." http://sscce.org/  Without this, we'll end up solving the code here with a fix that doesn't help you at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
auto c = children;
```

Where:

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<T>, N> children;
```

That would require copying `unique_ptr`s, and `unique_ptr` is not copyable. You can take a reference to `children` though:

```
auto& c = children; // OK
```